# getting "Didn't find class "org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64" Exception while updating payfort

Tags: android, payfort

I have tried updating **payfort** but still same
after calling this function. its crashing

```
    FortSdk.getInstance().registerCallback(PayFortSdkSample.this, fortrequest, FortSdk.ENVIRONMENT.PRODUCTION, 5, fortCallback, true, new FortInterfaces.OnTnxProcessed() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(Map<String, Object> map, Map<String, Object> map1) {
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(PayFortSdkSample.this, map1.get("response_message").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> map, Map<String, Object> map1) {
            try {
                showPage(map1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(PayFortSdkSample.this, map1.get("response_message").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Map<String, Object> map, Map<String, Object> map1) {
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(PayFortSdkSample.this, map1.get("response_message").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

> Error LogCat :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ae.mazadat.onlineauctionapp, PID: 10287
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64;
        at com.payfort.sdk.android.dependancies.security.aes.AESCipher.getDecryptedMessage(AESCipher.java:117)
        at com.payfort.sdk.android.dependancies.security.aes.AESCipherManager.decryptMsg(AESCipherManager.java:35)
        at com.payfort.fort.android.sdk.activities.InitSecureConnectionActivity$Handshake.onPostExecute(InitSecureConnectionActivity.java:153)
        at com.payfort.fort.android.sdk.activities.InitSecureConnectionActivity$Handshake.onPostExecute(InitSecureConnectionActivity.java:104)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:755)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:192)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:772)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ae.mazadat.onlineauctionapp-EGhuwTV5a2SRnsmbMWhx1g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ae.mazadat.onlineauctionapp-EGhuwTV5a2SRnsmbMWhx1g==/lib/x86, /data/app/ae.mazadat.onlineauctionapp-EGhuwTV5a2SRnsmbMWhx1g==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.payfort.sdk.android.dependancies.security.aes.AESCipher.getDecryptedMessage(AESCipher.java:117) 
        at com.payfort.sdk.android.dependancies.security.aes.AESCipherManager.decryptMsg(AESCipherManager.java:35) 
        at com.payfort.fort.android.sdk.activities.InitSecureConnectionActivity$Handshake.onPostExecute(InitSecureConnectionActivity.java:153) 
        at com.payfort.fort.android.sdk.activities.InitSecureConnectionActivity$Handshake.onPostExecute(InitSecureConnectionActivity.java:104) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:755) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:192) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:772) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: i had this issue,just added  implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.13'  maybe if your gradle is minifiEnabled true will not work

Answer (score 3):

implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.13'

minifyEnabled false